# ¿Puedo guardar los datos de "sudo pm2 logs <app-name>" en un archivo de texto?

Tags: nodejs, linux, pm2

Quiero guardar los "logs" que se generan cuando ejecuto el comando anterior en mi máquina pm2.
Conozco la ruta donde se guardan esos logs, pero yo quiero capturarlos en tiempo real, las últimas lineas, no todo el archivo out.log

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacer eso?

Comment: Para guardar los logs diarios en un archivo con nombre "fecha actual" y tener un control de esos logs

Comment: En general, duplicar logs no tiene mucho sentido ¿Cuál es el problema con los logs existentes?

Comment: Quiero llevar un control de esos logs diario, ya que los archivos son muy grandes.
Necesito un comando que me guarde dos archivos .log en uno.
He intentado con "cat" pero creo que solo es válido para .txt

Answer (score 0):

pm2 guarda los registros de forma predeterminada en $HOME/.pm2/logs/XXX-err.log, en dónde XXX es el nombre de la aplicacion en pm2.

#### EDICION

Si puedes escribir tu cron-job en un archivo separado. Cuando el servidor arranque puedes invocar tu cronjob, como en tu app.js o server.js. puedes exportar y exportar tu archivo cron job aqui

```
import cronJob from "../filename.js"        
server.listen(3000, () => {
   cronJob.start();
});
```

Puede crear y exportar módulos javascript en cualquier otro lugar de su aplicación express / node.js de esta manera:

#### app.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

require('./tasks/tasks')();

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

#### task.js

```
const cron = require('node-cron');

module.exports = () => {  
    cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
        console.log('running a task every minute');
    });
}
```

#### Terminal

```
[nodemon] starting `node start app.js`
App listening at http://localhost:5000
running a task every minute
```

#### Estructura de archivo:

```
/tasks
    tasks.js
app.js
```

Comment: Si, de eso estoy al tanto. Quiero saber si cuando ejecuto una aplicación node, si puedo exportar esos logs de alguna manera dentro de crontab de pm2